# "Some of the tornadoes can pack winds of 300 miles per hour"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm watching an episode of CNN Student News about tornadoes and taking notes of new words and collocations. A meteorologist just said:

> "Some of the tornadoes can pack winds of 300 miles per hour"

Although it can be understood generally, I'm not sure what *pack winds* exactly means in dictionary. I found [wind pack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wind-pack) which is a compound noun and doesn't match the video. There is no snow. I can roughly say it means *create* but it's not supported in dictionaries.

Thanks

Comment: "Some of *the* tornadoes" or "Some tornadoes".

Comment: You're right... I just edited that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about packing for a vacation. Things that you "pack" are things that you have with you.

You pack clothes. Tornadoes pack wind.

It's actually reasonably common to hear the word used non-literally like this. A very common phrase is "(x) **packs** a *punch*". The meaning here is that (x) **has** a *powerful effect*.